# How di I apply a class to a parent UL if it only has one child li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve the following using jQuery:

- Look through a list of ul's on a page and identify those with both (A) a specific class, and (B) with only 1 child LI element
- I then want to apply another class to those UL's

Here's what I have so far:

```
$("ul.class-to-look-for").each(function() {
    var totalLists = $(this).find("li").length;
    if (totalLists = 1) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("class-to-add");
    }
});
```

But this isn't working - am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Please post a sample HTML code.

Comment: why the `parent()` in the if?

Comment: Yeah it should just be `$(this).addClass("class-to-add");` but if that doesn't work please provide a full example that replicates the problem, including HTML CSS and JS

Comment: It should only be `$(this).addClass("class-to-add");`. `this` is already the `ul`

Comment: Just be careful using `.find("li")` as if you ever have nested `li'` then you will get incorrect results

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `only-child` selector which selects exactly what you need - some ul that has only one child li

```js
$('ul.classToLookFor li:only-child').parent().addClass('foo')
```

```css
.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="classToLookFor">
  <li>Foo</li>
</ul>

<ul class="classToLookFor">
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In place of `$(this).parent()` you have to use `$(this)` because you are looping through `ul`. So, `$(this)` it the object of the current `ul` with that class.

```js
$("ul.class-to-look-for").each(function() {
    var totalLists = $(this).find("li").length;
    if (totalLists == 1) {
        $(this).addClass("class-to-add");
    }
});
```

```css
.class-to-add {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="class-to-look-for">
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul class="class-to-look-for">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the only problem?

Comment: Hi, @musefan I think he have problem to find the element.

Comment: Yeah but you don't know for sure do you? Because the question doesn't contain all information to be sure

Comment: @musefan agreed with you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each("ul.class-to-look-for", function(index, matchingElement) {
    var totalLists = $(matchingElement).children("li");
    if (totalLists.length === 1) {
        $(matchingElement).addClass("class-to-add");
    }
});
```

If you're stuck, you can set a breakpoint in your developer tools on the second line and reload the page.

if it never hits the breakpoint, there is something wrong with your first UL selector.

if it DOES hit it, you can evaluate it to see what LI items it contains.